# Data Factory - is it possible to set a concurrency limit on a linked service?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure data factory with Azure Data Warehouse and I'd like to increase the Resource Class for my connection. In order to avoid tasks being forced to wait for concurrency slots to become available the database, I'd like to know if it is possible to tell data factory that it can only run 2 activities against a defined data source at a time. Hopefully,  this should help to prevent any time outs on tasks that are suspended in the db waiting for concurrency slots to become available.

My data factory has two parallel pipelines that could potentially be using the same db at the same time.

Is it possible to set a global concurrency limit for a linked service?

Comment: If you were using StoredProc activity I don't think that would parallelise beyond two in your scenario.  It's the Copy activity that has 'concurrency' and 'parallelCopies' attributes.  Review them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-copy-activity-performance#parallel-copy).

Comment: My problem is, I've got multiple stored proc activities, so I need some form of shared concurrency limit between all of them.

Comment: @wBob I'm Just asking if a StoreProc set a concurrency beyond 2 it will not work ?.Also even if we set concurrency as 2 for a Sp Activity.How would the Transaction in the Sp's will behave in case of any error occurred ?Is it hard to Control the Concurrency for an Sp with Transaction with a concurrency as 2 or more?

Comment: Stored Proc task does not parallelise in Azure Data Factory - it's the Copy activity that does that.

Comment: @wBob as you said we can't use concurrency Property under Policies for a SP Activities Right? Only copy Activity can be use those concurrency properties ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, **no**.

Currently ADF concurrency is set only at an activity level.

**Option 1**

You could create some fake datasets to enforce a dependency within ADF to chain the activities across pipelines. Not ideal and a little messy.

**Option 2**

Limit the resource class for the ADF connecting user in SQL DW and let it handle the query queuing rather than ADF. Be careful of your ADF time out values though, if you do this ADF will kill executions if the time out is exceeded because it isn't aware of operations within the service its invoked.

Hope this helps.